# Nurbs curve (2D) Fixed Length Parameterisation

Tags: c++11, math, geometry, nurbs

I have a class that represents a 2D Nurbs curve

class Nurbs2D {...};

The data members are control points (std::vector of Point2D), knot vector (std::vector of double), weights (std::vector of double), degree(implied based on num of control points and knot vector)

APIs: I am able to construct the curve parameterized between t0 & t1. I am also able to compute a Point2D given a parameter t (t0 <= t <= t1).

Given a parameter ti,  I want to estimate the next parameter ti+1, such that distance along the curve from ti to ti+1 is equal to Di (given Di within tolerance dt). Two functions are required, one to compute length from ti to ti+1 and another to estimate ti+1 given ti, Di and dt.

Code in C++ will be really useful. I am looking for speed over accuracy as tuning tolerance dt will bring the results to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the arc length of a NURBS curve is quite complicated. You need to integrate the length of the differential between two given parameter values. This gets messy even for simple quadratic B-splines as you can see in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/arc-length-of-b%C3%A9zier-curves).

Since you don't focus on accuracy, it is probably enough to approximate the length numerically. One of the answers under the Math.SE question pointed to a subdivision scheme that you could employ. You could extend this to NURBS. However, a simpler approach might be just as suitable for your application: Just evaluate the curve at a number of uniformly-spaced sample points in the interval you're interested in. Then, calculate the length of the polyline of this sampling. This approach can be improved by changing the sampling density based on curvature. But the uniform approach might work well enough for you. The accuracy correlates with the number of samples you use.

To get a point that is `dl` length units ahead of a current point `t`, you can do something similar: Choose a small increment `dt` and evaluate the points in that spacing (i.e., `t, t + dt, t + 2dt, t + 3dt ...`) while measuring the length of the polyline until your target length is reached. If you shoot over the target in the last interval, you can reduce `dt` for that last portion until you reach the required accuracy.